# Split string at different characters into 2d array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

When I want to split a string at a character and put it into an array I use:

```
var arr = data.split("\n");
```

This time however I need to split a string at different characters and need to store it into an 2d-array.
The string is as follows:

```
PMC12365AB       
PMC23456AB
PMC34567AB
```

The desired outcome

```
arr = [
    ["PMC", "12365", "AB"],
    ["PMC", "23456", "AB"],
    ["PMC", "34567", "AB"]
];
```

Any ideas

Comment: Loop over the array you get from the first split, and then split the individual items …?

Comment: Hint: use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) to split each of the elements of the array.

Comment: Exactly upon which character do you plan splitting "PMC12365AB" and have it produce `["PMC", "12365", "AB"]` ?

Comment: What is it specifically that you're confused about?

Comment: Can't you try to run a for loop and when the ASCII value of the letter changes then store it in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use regexp for this job. If you are already sure about the pattern of the text format (like n letters - m numbers - k letters) then you can simply use standard JS string operations like `substr`. However if you would like to give a little intelligence to this code then you can still do it by not touching regexp.

```js
var input  = "PMC12365AB\nPMCX2347756AB\nPMC34567ABCT0123";
    result = input.split("\n")
                  .map(s => [].reduce.call(s, (p,c) => isNaN(p[p.length-1]) === isNaN(c) ? p + c : p + "_" + c).split("_"));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
var input = "PMC12365AB\nPMC23456AB\nPMC34567AB";
var output = input.split('\n').map(function(line)
{
    var a = line.match(/^(...)(.....)(..)$/);
    a.shift();
    return a;
});
```

Obviously, the exact regex depends on how you want to cut each line, not sure if they're fixed-width, or based on letters vs numbers...

Comment: Why `a.shift()`?

Comment: Because the first element of the array returned by `match` is the complete match, then followed by the sub-expression matches, which are the only ones we want.

Comment: The regex would be for example: `line.match(/(\w+?)(\d+)(\w+)/)`

Comment: If it's based on letters / numbers / letters, yes. But OP hasn't specified exactly where to cut.